# Chave estrangeira SQL SET NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom pessoal vamos a mais uma duvida minha, espero que possam me ajudar.

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Quando eu crio uma **chave estrangeira** ligando a outro campo de outra tabela eu sempre defino ela como **CASCADE**. Porem quando vou cadastrar um campo (digamos que nessa tabela eu tenha mais **chaves estrangeiras** ligadas a ela e uma delas pode ser **NULL**) eu não consigo cadastrar com exito a tabela pelo fato dele nao encontrar na outra tabela **referenciada o valor**.

Creio eu que é por estar usando o tipo **CASCADE** e que **SET NULL** daria conta de deixar esse campo existir com o valor **NULL**.

Definindo minha chave estrangeira como **SET NULL** resolveira meu problema ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Nomes aos bois

A tabela **A** tem uma chave estrangeira da tabela **B**.

#### A solução

Defina o campo de **A** como `NULL`.

#### A explicação

O `CASCATE` de chaves estrangeiras são acionados quando ocorrem alterações ocorrem na tabela **referenciada**, não tabela referente. Nesse caso, um `CASCATE SET NULL` fará o campo de **A** ficar null **quando** o registro for apagado de **B**.

Esse é um caso diferente. Você quer que registros em **A** já nasçam sem um registro referente em **B**. Isso não tem nada a ver com `CASCATE`, mas sim como a própria definição em **A**.

Comment: Faz sentido kkkk, era disso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Logo mais vou testar e marco essa minha pergunta como respondida